# Outlook 2010 - using a VBA script in a rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook, script, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

I was following [the directions in a great post](https://superuser.com/questions/464000/how-to-replace-text-in-the-body-of-an-incoming-message-with-a-hyperlink-in-outlo) when I got to the step for selecting the name of the script to run.  I have VB code in ThisOutlookSession, but for some reason, the name of the procedure does not appear in the "Select Script" box.  I can step through the code in debug mode, so it seems to be syntactically correct.  What can be causing it to hide?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the wrong parameters in the script. Are you just passing in a MailItem? e.g.

```
Public Sub MacroName(email As MailItem)
    ' Your code here
End Sub
```

Once you've compiled it (Debug|Compile), it should show up in Outlook rules as an option. Note that if the parameters are wrong (i.e. you don't pass in just a MailItem) then it won't appear.

Comment: in the vba editor open the ThisOutlookSession and create a Public sub as rhys mentioned.  inside the sub goes your code.  make sure to put a proper end on the sub as well.  after the code is developed then one of the menu's has a compile and run option. once it is compiled it will show up in outlook as an option.  Im assuming you are trying to use it in a rule.  if so after the script is compiled it will be available in the custom script action in rules.