# Want to associate a private text to an outbound email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We send inquiries to various firms as a preliminary step pursuant to inviting bids on projects. I'd like to be able to create a plain text paragraph and 'associate' it to these outbound emails such that they do not get sent with the email, but are easy to access on the house copy we keep.

We thought of a variety of ways to do this, but they all seemed overkill. I'm hoping there's a clever approach around that isn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about if you emailed yourself the note, after sending the email. then the note appears in your send folder easy to find. just after that email.

Comment: You also might want to list out the "variety of ways to do this" that you already thought of, and give reasons why they are not suitable to your specific use case -- this could help us from having to guess at answers only to have them shot down because you won't use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Outlook Rules and Visual Basic for Applications to accomplish this. If that's something you've already looked at and determined it's "overkill" or don't like it for some other reason, too bad -- you're going to have to get your hands dirty with some code to get this done because it's such a custom request.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/464027/144607) which I provided for another similar-ish problem might be useful. You may be able to adapt some of the methods used there to your specific use case, but you'll have to know what you are doing. If you *don't* know what you're doing and no one at your office has any experience with Visual Basic for Applications programming or Outlook rules, you probably should hire a consultant.

Comment: I had considered VB, as I use it a bit for Excel work, but it seems like the learning curve to get up to speed on the specifics for Outlook would take more time than I have. That said, your similar-ish idea looks good at first glance. If I can modify that so I 'insert' the #123456 in my outgoing mail it will come back in any reply, which puts the info I created immediately at hand. @barlop, tnx for the idea, but it doubles the number of emails in the system (not good). - Jim

Comment: If you don't have enough time to learn VBA, you may as well abandon the effort to even do this. Solutions take time OR money -- if you have neither, you're out of luck. There's no "pre-canned" software out there that does precisely what you want.